# errors during compiling a linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I was trying to compile a linux-3.16 kernel, everything is fine before make modules_install.
At the middle of modules_install, an error occurs

```
/lib/modules/3.16.0s3362938/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/iuu_phoenix.ko~ at ./scripts/sign-file line 417.
make[1]: *** [drivers/usb/serial/iuu_phoenix.ko] Error 28
make: *** [_modinst_] Error 2
```

I tried to search the solutions but failed, can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: Firstly, off-topic, try super-user. Secondly, what does line 417 of  scripts/sign-file say?

Comment: i'm using super-user. and 417 says "close FD || die $dest;"

Comment: *"Error 28"* -- No space left on device?

Comment: thanks for the tips. I am new to VBox and Linux, so there are lots of things that I don't understand. I will check to expand the storage and try again.

Answer (score 0):

*"Error 28"* -- No space left on device? –  sawdust